# Is it a good practice to initialize a dynamically allocated structure with all 0 using memset(), if yes what are the benefits?

Tags: c, initialization, structure, heap-memory

In a client-server system where its possible that server may populate only some of the IE and rest has to be treated as default value (0) at client side.

For such a system, is it a good idea to do `memset(.., 0, ...)` of dynamically allocating memory for the received message before copying the contents of message?

Comment: There's no general answer to this. If you needed zero initialized memory then use `calloc()`. Otherwise, whether zeroing out is required or not depends on what you do with it. For example, if you are writing a C-string into the allocated memory using `snprintf()` then there's no need to zero initialize it before writing into it.

Comment: No use in clearing memory if you are going to overwrite it by copying something else into it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to initialise memory which immediately gets overwritten after initialisation.

Also unused memory does not need to be initialised. ("unused" here means, that it will never be read.)

All other memory needs to be initialised. Whether this would be done by using `memset()` and writing `0`s to it depends on the specific context and use-case.